# Can I transmit the host microphone voice to the remote host via TeamViewer Remote Access?

Tags: remote-access, teamviewer, microsoft-teams

need to transmit the voice of host to the remote computer to attend meeting on the remote side via TeamViewer

Comment: To what end? Why not just run TV on the local machine?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.